# change background image using js

Tags: javascript, web-deployment

I am not able to change the background image of a division in my project website.
I am using this code in js file:

```
  document.getElementsByClassName("home").style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/background4.jpg')";
```

my div in html is:

```
<div id="intro" class='home' align='center'>
```

also my js file is located in `project/js/script.js`
images are located in `project/images/background4.jpg`
and index.html is in `project/index.html`

I am not able to find out the mistake!

### EDIT

I also tried `document.getElementById()`
but that also doesn't works.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName returns an array

Comment: Try this instead document.getElementById('intro').style.backgroundImage="url('../images/background4.jpg')"

Comment: you could use jQuery:
jQuery("#intro").css("background-image","url('paper.gif')");

Comment: @Magnus I tried that but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base path context is defined by index, not by script.js (is not PHP) :

```
// index.html = ./project/
// execute index.html/js/script.js
// loading index.html/images/background4.jpg
document
  .getElementsByClassName('home')[0]
    .style
      .backgroundImage = "url('images/background4.jpg')";
```

inscpect DevTools:Network in you browser (right click : inspect).

have nice day.

Comment: Wrong, what return `.getElementsByClassName(...)`?

Comment: so ... the reason of [0] for target first .home element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to target your div using `document.getElementById('intro')`, not `getElementsByClassName('home')`.
`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, not an element.

Edit : And yes, as Evehne said, the path should be "images/", not "../images" as you would do in a css file for example.

Comment: Note that you'd better use getElementById instead of getElementsByClassName[0] which is very slower.